# Eclipse: Programmatically closing perspective after application starts

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I am writing plugin for an Eclipse application. I wrote a custom perspective `com.app.custom.ui.perspectives.MyCustomWorkspace` to show few custom views and some views already provided by the application. So essentially my custom perspective is similar to one of the ootb perspectives, `com.app.ui.perspectives.MyWorkspace`, plus few of my custom views. One of the common views shared by my perspective and ootb perspective is `com.app.ui.views.ViewerView`.

If I start the application with `-perspective com.app.ui.perspectives.MyWorkspace` argument, the `ViewerView` view loads just fine. However, if I start the application with `-perspective com.app.custom.ui.perspectives.MyCustomWorkspace` argument, the `ViewerView` view does not load and throws an exception. I went back and forth with the application vendor to get support, but no avail. Here is relevant exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.app.common.viewer.AutoCheckoutHelper.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.app.viewer.view.PanelViewer.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.app.ui.views.ViewerViewPart.createViewer(Unknown Source)
  at com.app.ui.views.ViewerViewPart.createContent(Unknown Source)
  at com.app.ui.views.ViewerViewPart.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
```

After some trial and error, I found that if I open `MyWorkspace` first, and then open `MyCustomWorkspace`, I don't get any exceptions loading `ViewerView` view, regardless of if the `MyWorkspace` remains open or is closed.

So, my question - **After the application starts and the `MyWorkspace` loads first, how do I programmatically close `MyWorkspace` and open `MyCustomWorkspace`**? I looked for perspective listeners, but could not find one that would be fired after perspective is finished loading. Is there any workbench or workbench window or application listeners that I could use.

I thought of using `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` to add my custom views to the ootb `MyWorkspace` perspective, but some of my custom views are added conditionally depending upon who the user is. `perspectiveExtensions` does not seem to provide any functionality to add conditions.

**Edit-1**: Removed the original reference to `e4` application from my original post:

> I am writing plugin for an Eclipse `e4` application

**Edit-2**: Adding more clarification:
All perspectives (custom as well as application provided) are defined using `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives` extension point, and all views (custom as well as application provided) are defined using `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point.

**Edit-3**: Added exception details in the post.

Comment: Note any org.eclipse.ui.xxxx extension point or plug-in is not e4 and won't work in a pure e4 app - are you really doing e4 (just plug-ins from the org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature)? You use `EPartService.switchPerspective` to switch perspectives.

Comment: From which listener code should I call `EPartService.switchPerspective`? I am guessing that I will have to switch perspective once the `MyWorkspace` is completely loaded.

The application is not pure e4 application at this time. I am migrating the plugin from old version of the application, so I suppose I will work on converting my plugin to pure e4 once the app goes to pure e4. I will edit my original post to remove reference to `e4`.

Comment: _"...throws an exception..."_ - Which (if it's a ClassNotFoundException, something might be wrong with your dependencies)? Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: @howlger: I am getting NullPointerException. I have added relevant exception stack trace in the original post.

Comment: I just need to know the listener to use that will fire when application startup is complete. That will be when the loading of the initial perspective will be complete. That will be the ideal place to switch the perspective.

Comment: So the `NullPointerException` is the root problem preventing the perspective to be created, right? Does the NPE happen in your code or in the code of the vendor from whom you don't get support?

Comment: @howlger: NPE occurs in vendor code during initialization of vendor provided `ViewerView` when it's part of custom `MyCustomWorkspace` perspective and it's loaded at startup. However, if vendor provided `MyWorkspace` perspective (`ViewerView` is part of it too) is loaded at startup, no exception is thrown. If the `MyWorkspace` perspective is loaded first at the startup and then manually switched to `MyCustomWorkspace` perspective, then also no exception is thrown. I am just looking for ways to switch to `MyCustomWorkspace` perspective programmatically after application initialization.

Comment: Did you try to programmatically switch the perspective using the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to workaround this bug in the vendor code? You might consider to give your `MyCustomWorkspace` code as minimal reproducible example to the vendor, so they can fix their bug.

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. I used `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().setPerspective()` to set `MyCustomWorkspace` perspective as active perspective.. However, the call to `getActiveWorkbenchWindow()` returns null. Maybe the `earlyStartup` is way too early before even application is finished initializing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bunch of trial and errors, I found a solution (well, sort of)...

I added Perspective Listener and inside the `perspectiveActivated` method, I called `setPerspective` to set `MyCustomWorkspace` perspective. However simply by calling `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().setPerspective()` threw exception. So I made the call as follows to set my custom perspective:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() ->
{
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().setPerspective(...)
}
```

That does not throw any exceptions. It loads `MyCustomWorkspace`. However it messes with the menus and toolbar icons. Many of them don't show up. But that's the battle for some other time.